# ) becomes 9 in print-out

Tags: pdftex, printing

I have the following expression `\mathfrak{U}^{(\alpha,N)}`. The pdf output generated with `pdflatex` is all right. But the printer turns the `)` into a `9`. Has probably something to do with the printer driver.

Is there any general way to prevent such things (like `\protect` or `{)}` for example)?

Further notes and information:

- I can't test possible solutions since the problem doesn't occur with my own printer and I have no access to the printer in question. Also I cannot provide information about the printer in question. The printing was done in a big copy shop and I doubt whether they still know which printer they used for my document.
- My document has almost 300 pages. The expression `\mathfrak{U}^{(\alpha,N)}` appears on average once per page. The problem however occurs on only one single page (or so I believe ... impossible to check all).
- I use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. Adobe Acrobat however says that there also type 3 fonts in my document, see the following screenshots from the acrobat document properties window [image: screenshot 1] [image: screenshot 2] [image: screenshot] 
  (translation: "In diesem Dokument verwendete Schriften" = "fonts used in this document", "benutzerdefiniert" = "defined by user", "Originalschrift" = "original font", "Kodierung" = "encoding")

  I can't see any connection with the expression in question (but then I don't know anything about this font business!).
- Consider the following MWE (compile with `pdflatex`). Checking the document properties reveals that there are only type 1 fonts. So again, there doesn't seem to be any connection with type 3 fonts appearing in the original document and my problem. As noted above, I cannot check what happens when I print the pdf (with the printer in question).

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\mathfrak{U}^{(\alpha,N)}$
\end{document}
```

---

- I load the following packages (just in case that info helps):

---

```
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}                
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                           
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}                                         
\usepackage{setspace}   
\usepackage{amsmath}                               
\usepackage{amssymb}                               
\usepackage{bbm}                                   
\usepackage{mathtools}                             
\usepackage{dlfltxbcodetips}                       
\usepackage{textcomp}                              
\usepackage{scrtime}                               
\usepackage{enumerate}                                                        
\usepackage{fancybox}                              
\usepackage{booktabs}                              
\usepackage{caption}\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}    
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,hyperref,framed{ntheorem}                                     \usepackage{color}                                 
\usepackage{framed}                                
\usepackage{url}                                   
\usepackage{graphicx}                              
\usepackage{subfigure}      
\usepackage{pifont}                                
\usepackage{tensor}         
\usepackage{xspace}                                
\usepackage{chngcntr}                                                                      \usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}                    
\usepackage{titlesec}       
\usepackage{titletoc}                              
\usepackage{refcount}       
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[fit]{truncate}  
\usepackage[
  a4paper,                                    
  textwidth=16cm,                             
  outer=2cm,
  textheight=45\baselineskip,
  headheight=\baselineskip,
  includehead=true,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{emptypage} 
\usepackage{imakeidx}                              
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[pdfstartview=FitH,         
            plainpages=false,          
            hyperfootnotes=false,      
            pdfauthor={lpdbw},        
            pdftitle={title},
            pdfsubject={XYZ},
            pdfkeywords={math},
            pdfproducer={LaTeX with hyperref},
            pdfcreator={PDFLaTeX}
            ]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
```

---

Comment: Do you use `fontenc`?

Comment: Yes --> `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` on a WinVista machine (in case that matters) ... should I use something different?

Comment: This really seems a printer driver problem. Check the PDF file font properties with Adobe Reader in order to see if some font is listed as Type3.

Comment: I have edited my question taking into account your comments!

Comment: Are there included graphics in the same page where the error occurs?

Comment: How is the encoding for the input? Does it match with the package inputenc (\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc})? Maybe you declare \usepackage[T1]{inputenc} but your editor uses utf8 or vice versa.

Comment: @egreg: Well, the error occurs on page 35, on page 37 there is a picture `\includegraphics{xyz.pdf}` ...

Comment: @lazyboy: I load `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` ...

Comment: Is it possible that any of the loaded packages causes the problem, that is, should I tell you which packages I load?

Comment: Yes, maybe it can help to diagnose the error. Does your text editor use the encoding latin1 too?

Comment: OK, I edited my question and added package information.

Comment: I don't know which encoding my editor uses; it's WinEdt 5.6 by the way.

Comment: Considering your MWE I cannot reprocedure the pdf file with T3 Encoding, event when I use all your packages. I have not WinVista, so I use a win XP with TeXLive 2012. I compile the files with pdflatex, encoding ISO-8859-15. I think WinEdt uses the encoding by default ISO-8859-15 (also T1 correct me if I'm wrong) But I'm not sure.